# Is there a word for congruence between a software platform’s purpose or structure and the actual experience of using it?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for congruence between a software platform's purpose or structure and the actual experience of using it?

For example, is there a word for the congruence of the purpose, structure, workflow of a collaborative learning software platform and the actual experience and process of using the platform for learning collaboration?

Example:

> Our SaaS platform's deeper learning workflow is fully __________________ (congruent?) with the actual process of using deeper learning for professional growth.

Comment: I thinka  intuitive is the  word you are looking for; change your sentence structure as necessary.

Comment: The model [or platform supporting the model] fully ***reflects/mirrors*** the actual process being modeled.

Comment: You could use "consistent" if you don't want to change the rest of the sentence.

Comment: fully coheres with the actual process of using deeper learning etc.

Comment: Also, is fully aligned with...

Comment: "Our SaaS fosters deeper learning by reinforcing/supporting the natural processes of professional growth." still sounds like puffery to me, but a better grade of it, at least. (Maybe that's helpful. Not sure if the example is even relevant to you, but in case it is...)

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to get away from puffery...always a challenge for me, requiring many iterations...:-)

Comment: I am currently at "Both the platform user experience and the embedded professional learning experience fully cohere with the actual process of Deeper Learning inquiry."  Would like simpler still, but this says it.

Comment: Or, "Both the platform user experience and the embedded professional learning ARE the actual processes of Deeper Learning."

Comment: "are fully in harmony with" ?

Comment: This is often referred to as "fitness for purpose".

Comment: entirely natural

Answer (score 1):

For your sample, the first word that came to my mind was ***integrated***:

> With various parts or aspects linked or coordinated.
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries<](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/integrated)/sub></sub>

It works nicely in your sample:

> Our SaaS platform's deeper learning workflow is fully ***integrated*** with the actual process of using deeper learning for professional growth.

However, if you want a word more focused on the experience of the participant, you can borrow from virtual reality terminology: ***immersive***:

> seeming to surround the audience, player, etc. so that they feel completely involved in something:
>   • *an immersive theatrical experience*
>   • *The new game is more immersive.*
>   [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/immersive)

Unfortunately, using ***immersive*** directly in your example is a bit awkward, so I have reworded it slightly:

> Our SaaS platform's deeper learning workflow is fully ***immersive***, enabling the actual process of using deeper learning for professional growth.

But if the exact wording is important, you could used ***immersed***:

> Our SaaS platform's deeper learning workflow is fully ***immersed*** with the actual process of using deeper learning for professional growth.

Answer (score 0):

One thing fully coheres with another.
The purpose of this software coheres with user experience.

Comment: Thanks, Lambie!  This is getting at it and I am using this .  It is close to the nature of what I am seeking. Actually, it is almost ontological ... the nature of one and the other are the same. the software, the process, and the purpose are coherent, actually, the same. Thanks again!

Comment: They meld into one thing.

Comment: These downvotes are ridiculous: to be coherent with is to cohere.

Answer (score 0):

("Congruent" does fit as does "coherent")

In your context:

"Mimetic" means that a thing mimics another thing.

"Complient" means a thing that fits the requirements of another.

"Harmonious" means a thing works beautifully with another thing.

I'd suggest dropping "is fully" and replacing with "mimics", "matches" , or "copies", though. That is shorter and probably says the same thing you intend.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Yes, but more....I am trying to get at the almost ontological nature of the connection. See above. All this thinking has helped me clarify my thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: Fair enough. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

"... fully aligned ... "

Although "coheres" is glorious!

Answer (score 0):

You could say that they are ***[in tune](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20tune)*** with each other:

> in a state in which one thing agrees with or matches another —usually + *with* • His formal clothing was in tune with the occasion.
>   *<sub>from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20tune)</sub>*

This can also be stated as "in harmony".

Answer (score 0):

You can say that they are *[correspondent](https://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/unabridged/correspondent)*:

> 1:  having a relation of likeness :  being similar or analogous to
> something
>
> 2:  being in agreement :  suiting, fitting — used with *with* or *to*

So your sentence becomes:

> Our SaaS platform's deeper learning workflow is fully *correspondent*
> with the actual process of using deeper learning for professional
> growth.